# How to get additional and missed data from 2 excels using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 excel csv files as below

```
df1 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink'], 'Count': [1, 1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=df1.keys())

df2 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink', 'SC-002_Signinlink'], 'Count': [1, 2, 1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=df2.keys())
```

I wanted to compare both data, I could do it by using below...

```
  df_compare = df1.merge(df2, on='Transaction_Name', suffixes=('_df1','_df2'))
df_compare[['Count_df1','Count_df2']] = df_compare[['Count_df1','Count_df2']].astype(float).astype(int)
print (df_compare)
```

But in df1 SC-001_Homepage is exists and it is not there in df2. With the above code i am not getting the result for SC-001_Homepage. Also in df2 SC-002_Signinlink is there and it is not available in df1. This value also missing from the result. can someone help me how to include these transactions in the result?

Expected result should be like...

```
 Transaction_Name    Count_df1  Count_df2
0   SC-001_Homepage       1       0
1   SC-002_Homepage       1       1
2   SC-001_Signinlink     2       2
3   SC-002_Signinlink     0       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1.merge(df2,on=['Transaction_Name'],how='outer',suffixes=('_df1','_df2')).fillna(0)

    Transaction_Name  Count_df1  Count_df2
0    SC-001_Homepage        1.0        0.0
1    SC-002_Homepage        1.0        1.0
2  SC-001_Signinlink        2.0        2.0
3  SC-002_Signinlink        0.0        1.0
```

If you want to convert the float to int,use:

```
df_new[df_new.select_dtypes(['float']).columns]= df_new.select_dtypes(['float']).astype(int)
```

Comment: Pleasure..!! All the best. :)

Comment: Can you also please help me how to find the % difference between Count_df1 and Count_df2? Below is the sample expected output.


`Transaction_Name  Count_df1  Count_df2    Diff
0    SC-001_Homepage        1.0        0.0          (1-0)/1`

Comment: Difference formula should be (Count_df1-Count_df2)/Count_df1

Comment: @SwethaGorantla , i wouldnot understand like this :( its advisable to post a fresh question, i can get the picture and answer there. :) also SO does not recommend iterative debugging. :)

Comment: Thanks i will a post a new question